# How to get the subject dynamically in HTML signature in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, email-signature, exim

I need to add a WeTransfer link in Thunderbird HTML signature to allow clients upload files directly in my account.

I want to give them the WeTransfer link with pre-filled title based on subject of email `https://wetransfersupport.wetransfer.com/?title=EMAIL%20SUBJECT` to recognize any response of that.

I tried SmartTemplates add-on and if I set `%subject%` as plain text works successfully.

```
<a href="https://wetransfersupport.wetransfer.com" target="_blank">Upload your files</a> Please use Subject <strong>%subject%</strong>
```

But SmartTemplates add-on doesn't work if is in an HREF attribute.

```
<a href="https://wetransfersupport.wetransfer.com?title=%subject%" target="_blank">Upload your files</a>
```

Is there anything else like `{{EMAIL_SUBJECT}}` to add in title parameter?

Or even better can I add any code in `Exim Configuration Manager / Advanced Editor` or somewhere else το replace `my_custom_text` with subject?

Comment: Based on WeTransfer https://help.wetransfer.com/hc/en-us/articles/11389231228306-How-to-add-a-pre-filled-title-and-message-to-your-custom-WeTransfer-URL should be `?title=`

Comment: This is my scenario, for WeTransfer link and Subject variable. Imagine to have emoji on your HTML signature to response about the experience of support. The link redirects to your webpage and you need to recognize the response by Message ID instead of Subject. How could you get the Message ID in your HTML Signature link as get variable to save it in your database?

Comment: Via SmartTemplates add-on the link on HTML Signature is https://wetransfersupport.wetransfer.com/?title=%3Csmarttemplate%20hdr=%27subject%27%20st4variable=%27subject%27%20title=%27subject%27%20class=%27noWrite%27%3ESubject%3C/smarttemplate%3E . WeTrasnfer recognize it and pass get variable in subject. So, i don't believe that should be a question for WeTransfer. Also i asked Thunderbird about this and suggested me SmartTamplates, Mail Merge add Quicktext add-ons. Only SmartTemplates was nearly in that i want, but i doesn't work as I expected. This is the reason why I talked about Exim.

Comment: "But it doesn't work if is in an HREF attribute." this sounds like it is going to be an improperly escaped `%`. You say "it doesn't work" but what is actually emitted when you apply that portion of the template?

Comment: I have an email with subject `Customer ID xxxxx / Report 2024 / Jan-Mar`. I want an HREF attribute lin my HTML Signature like "https://inkdesign.wetransfer.com/?title=Customer ID xxxxx / Report 2024 / Jan-Mar". Instead of this, via SmartTemplates i get `https://inkdesign.wetransfer.com/?title=<smarttemplate hdr='subject' st4variable='subject' title='subject' class='noWrite'>Subject</smarttemplate>`. Maybe SmartTemplates doesn't work like this. Also i edited my question

Comment: Can you please EDIT your question to add some of this additional detail to the question itself, making your question more clear and complete?